# What does the statement do? ElementMatcher in Bytebuddy

Tags: byte-buddy

Anyone can explain what is the statement do exactly? Why does it wrapped a layer into a layer.

The matcher is:

```
ElementMatchers.declaresMethod(ElementMatchers
  .isAnnotatedWith(ElementMatchers.named("com.agent.tool.Trace")))
```

Applied to this code:

```
package com.agent.tool

@Target({ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.PACKAGE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Trace {

  String[] argumentName() default {};
}
```

Can I write in this way

```
ElementMatchers.declaresMethod("com.agent.tool.Trace")
```

or

```
ElementMatchers.declaresMethod((ElementMatchers
   .isAnnotatedWith("com.agent.tool.Trace"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Byte Buddy element matchers can often be nested to match even complex conditions by combinining several annotations. If you wanted to match any method that is annotated with an annotation of a specific name, you need one additional matcher `named`:

```
declaresMethod(isAnnotatedWith(named("com.agent.tool.Trace")))
```